# How to deal with questions that are not getting an answer, and you no longer need an answer to, but may help others in the future

Tags: discussion, answers, close-reasons, unanswered-questions

An example is my recent question here:

[Unable to use igraph function 'all_simple_paths'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57006452/unable-to-use-igraph-function-all-simple-paths?noredirect=1#comment100677456_57006452)

It did not receive an answer. The issue was not resolved, and I just went about a different way of doing things; I coded up my own path finder, although it was essentially an amalgamation of other people's suggestions. It also wasn't particularly efficient anyway. For those two reasons, I would not want to post that code as an 'answer' to the question.

That being said, the error I was receiving was a true one, and other people may encounter it in the future. I wondered whether it was best to close my question, or leave it open- perhaps with a comment at the top that I personally no longer need an answer.

EDIT: A thought in response to the answer already given; I suppose that even if a post never receives an answer, but it is written well with source code and what the OP has tried, then one of the OP's attempts may well be the solution to someone else's difficulty.

Comment: Nobody [likes this](https://xkcd.com/979/).  You can easily avoid it by deleting your unnecessary question.

Comment: @HansPassant My question has only been there for a day. I have often seen SO posts receive their first (and very useful) andswers a few days after they were posted. But I would almost certainly forget in a few days that I had posted the question, to see if it needs deletion. **Perhaps that could be an added feature to SO?** i.e. notify the user if they have a question that has been stagnant for a week, and ask if they would like to delete it.

Answer (score 17):

SO is meant to be source of knowledge and not just lets-help-you site.

So even if your question is not relevant for you **but it can help others in the future** I believe you should keep it there.

You may post the different way you took as some other people who will encounter this issue may use the same logic and the new way as you did.

**Edit** - I agree with the insight you added: if question is well format and explain, even when not answered it can help other people.

It is just anther reason why to keep a good question (they not a common as it seems...)